# Combine results from 2 standard set controllers or add to the read only results. Is there any way to do this?

Tags: apex, soql, standardsetcontroller

I have an extension for a custom child object. I need to build a list of all child records + create new child records for the parent that does not yet have a child record... and then paginate over that list, before inserting records.

Any ideas how to do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you'll have to use the alternative StandardSetController syntax, namely the one that accepts a list:

```
// clone to clear the list read-only attribute
SObject[] allRecords = [SELECT Id... FROM Child].clone(), 
          newRecords = new SObject[0];
// Add records to newRecords, then...
allRecords.addAll(newRecords);
stdCtrl = new ApexPages.StandardController(allRecords);
```